# Cong, subst and equality type in dependently typed programming languages

Tags: coq, agda, dependent-type, idris

In dependently typed type theory there's a equality type. Usually when this type is defined, a number of utilities, namely cong and subst are introduced. How expressive they are? Is it possible to express everything we can with eliminator for equality with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't prove uniqueness of identity proofs only with cong, subst and eliminator.

```
uip : {α : Level} {A : Set α} {x y : A} -> (p q : x ≡ y) -> p ≡ q
```

Here is the explanation: http://homotopytypetheory.org/2011/04/10/just-kidding-understanding-identity-elimination-in-homotopy-type-theory/

Comment: I think the question was whether we can use subst and cong to prove the standard J elimination rule. I'm not sure what the answer to this question is, but I'm guessing no as well.

Comment: Yes, the question was about ability to express elimination rule with these primitive. As far as I understand, what you mentioned is the Axiom K, right? (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+K)

Comment: Ah, I see now. Sorry for that. Yes, my answer is about the axiom K.